# Is there a way to view PhantomJS console.log messages via Selenium/GhostDriver?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm using the Java bindings of [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) to run Selenium acceptance tests against PhantomJS.

If one of the web pages requested by PhantomJS logs to the Javascript console via console.log, is there a way to capture or view those messages?

I'm guessing that the answer to this is forehead-slappingly simple but I can't work it out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser");
```

Comment: Yes, that should now work since that part of the [WebDriver Wire Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) was [implemented](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/279) in GhostDriver a few weeks ago. i.e. it should work with GhostDriver 1.1.0. Once PhantomJS is upgraded to embed GhostDriver 1.1.0 all should be rosy. Therefore I'm going to accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: 1.9.6 of phantomjs should have it :)

Comment: Yes, it should do. Unfortunately the combination of PhantomJS/GhostDriver in 1.9.6 is a bit bricked because of this: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11915. It sounds like a 1.9.7 release to fix the issue is imminent though. I'll update when I've been able to make use of the new release. (This is assuming that they go down the fix-forward route rather than rollback to GhostDriver 1.0 of course!)

Comment: How would you do this in C#? There is no `Logs` method on the manage object.

Comment: Ever figure this out @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen ?

Comment: Yes, in a hackish way. I overwrote the onError method on the page object to add a `div` with a specific class on error with all the details in it. Then, from my unit tests, I made helper methods to check if such error `div`s were encountered.

Comment: The current WebDriver version 2.53.0.0 has a Logs property: driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(OpenQA.Selenium.LogType.Browser)